# Adicionar PRIContexto no mapa Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

Fiz um mapa de raiz e gostaria de apresentar o nome da empresa no cabeçalho.

Podem ajudar-me a resolver este desafio sff?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para saber o contexto da empresa basta adicionar esta formula ao seu mapa.

```
pso.Mapas.Inicializar("GCP");

var strFormula = new StringBuilder();
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Nome:='{bso.Contexto.IDNome}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Morada:='{bso.Contexto.IDMorada}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Localidade:='{bso.Contexto.IDLocalidade}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar CodPostal:='{bso.Contexto.IDCodPostal} {bso.Contexto.IDCodPostalLocal}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Telefone:='{bso.Contexto.IDTelefone}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Fax:='{bso.Contexto.IDFax}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Contribuinte:='{bso.Contexto.IFNIF}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar CapitalSocial:='{bso.Contexto.ICCapitalSocial}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Conservatoria:='{bso.Contexto.ICConservatoria}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar Matricula:='{bso.Contexto.ICMatricula}';");
strFormula.Append($"StringVar MoedaCapitalSocial:='{bso.Contexto.ICMoedaCapSocial}';");

pso.Mapas.SetFormula("DadosEmpresa", strFormula.ToString());
```